# JqueryUI Sortable scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have initialized `#items` as jquery sortable, to make item list sortable.
`#items` is a child div of a parent div `#content`.

The parent div `#content` has a max-height set 40%, and is allowed to scroll in case of overflow. Here is the css:

```
#content {//parent-div
    border-right: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    height: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the css for child div `#items`:

```
#items {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Whenever I try to swap **Item1** with **Item18** while sorting, I am not able to do so, as #items is not being scrolled to bottom.

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E2Hg/107/)** .

How to make `#items` scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're specifying `overflow` properties on your sortable `#items`, which seems to be preventing ui from doing it's on thing.

```
#items {
 /* remove these
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; */
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E2Hg/109/)