# jQuery UI Draggable Scroll Issue with Helper Clone()

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am creating a application where user can drag images and drop onto a div. But images are large so that  the droppable div can be at the bottom of the page. Hence I need a functionality where when user drag an image and try to drag to the bottom of the page to get to the droppable div, page should scroll.

Here is my code for draggable

```
$(".drag-img").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    scroll: true,
    revert: "invalid" ,
    helper: function(){
        $copy = $(this).clone();
        return $copy;
    },
    appendTo: 'body',
    scroll: false
});
```

Jquery UI has option 'scroll':true, but it won't work with clone() helper. Do you have any suggestions or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal demo where it doesn't work with clone helper? as far as i know, it works fine. Probably it's an issue with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your overflow div with a div with position: relative; and adding position: relative; to your overflow div

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<div style="position:relative; background-color: red; width: 500px; height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
    <table id="nfTable" class="treeTable">
        <tr><td><span class="parent initialized expanded">drop here</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="draggable">drag me</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="draggable">drag me</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="draggable">drag me</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="droppable">drop here</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="droppable">drop here</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="draggable">drag me</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="draggable">drag me</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="draggable">drag me</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="draggable">drag me</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="droppable">drop here</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="droppable">drop here</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="droppable">drop here</span></td></tr>
        <tr><td><span class="droppable">drop here</span></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) docs:

> [**scroll**](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scroll)  Default: `true`
>
> If set to true, container auto-scrolls while dragging.

This works fine regardless helper is clone or not. Make sure you're not specifying css `overflow`  properties for the elements you're initializing with UI.

Possibly related:  [JqueryUI Sortable scrolling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678106/jqueryui-sortable-scrolling)